# How to turn off internal sharing links for all in a subsite

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-permission-level, sharing

I am the site collection administrator of a site which has multiple subsites. Each subsite has its own owners(Full control) and members(contribute) groups.

Access request settings for the subsites is:

- Allow members to share the site and individual files and folders: NO
- Allow access requests: YES
- Select who will receive all access requests on this site: Subsite Owners group

The owners are given full control so that they could approve access requests to files/folders in their subsites. But, at the same time, I do not want owners to create internal sharing links that can be shared with other subsite members, yet internal.

Is there a way to turn off internal sharing links on a subsite level without turning off the access requests to Owners group? Or is there a permission level that can be assigned to Owners group which let them approve access but not to share files/folders via links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my knowledge, there is no way to turn off internal sharing links on a subsite  without turning off the access requests to owners group. And creating a permission level that can be assigned to owners group which let them approve access but not abled to share files and folders via links. Because once they have full control permission, they can share files and folders via links.